# ASP.NET help page for ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm new to C# and I just wanted to know if there is a way to integrate ASP.NET help page for my ASP.NET Core Web API.

I saw many tutorials where they have said that upon installing the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage` Nuget package, it'll automatically create an `Area` folder with a `HelpPage` folder, but upon installing that package the folder isn't created.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and the ASP.NET Core Web API project template where I already have a project running CRUD operations with Swagger Implementation but I wanted the documentation similar to ASP.NET HelpPage.

If anyone knows how to do this please do let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This package seems to be for ASP.Net framework not for core projects. if it is a static data and intension is just to provide information about API's then you can generate a static html and serve on an endpoint. but if you want to generated automatically then you would have to go with swagger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [SwashBuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle) or [NSwag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag) for generating the API documentation in ASP Core projects