# Migration of ASP.NET 4.6 Help Pages to .NET 6 (.net core)

Tags: api, .net-core, .net-6.0

In .NET framework we have support of Creating Help Page for Web API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages

Does this feature supported in .NET 6. We are migrating our legacy ASP.NET framework application to .NET6.

How to migrate this feature to .NET6? If it is not supported in .Net6(.net core) how can we achieve the similar functionality in .Net core

I am trying to migrate this feature to .net core but I am facing issues on how to load the app data, register HelpdataConfig in .net core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [ASP.NET help page for ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72761812/1539100), the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage#readme-body-tab) is for ASP.NET and does not for ASP.NET CORE or .NET 6, so you have to migrate this library to some popular Web API documentation libraries like Swagger

As you can see in [ASP.NET Core web API documentation with Swagger / OpenAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-7.0), you can use below documentation

By [Christoph Nienaber](https://twitter.com/zuckerthoben) and [Rico Suter](https://blog.rsuter.com/)

Swagger (OpenAPI) is a language-agnostic specification for describing REST APIs. It allows both computers and humans to understand the capabilities of a REST API without direct access to the source code. Its main goals are to:

- Minimize the amount of work needed to connect decoupled services.
- Reduce the amount of time needed to accurately document a service.

The two main OpenAPI implementations for .NET are [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) and [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag), see:

- [Getting Started with Swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)
- [Getting Started with NSwag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)